# Problem with display with chrome

Tags: google-chrome, display

When a play with the size of the window and return to the full screen I got a display problem on the top of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: Yes I think : alexandre@alexandre-Ubuntu-PC:~$ google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 42.0.2311.90

Comment: Same as me. As a total guess I would say that it's yet another Unity bug. I use Gnome 2 and it's not an issue.

Comment: okok :/ thx ....

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have fixed the issue permanently, as far as I've seen.

Open Chrome, leave it maximized, close it and then reopen it. It's surprisingly simple.

Comment: That's a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: @KenSharp Well, it fixes it permanently, so I think it's a solution. It only happens when Chrome is opened for the first time. There's no "solution" since it's only temporary.